# How to Fix undefined method error in the application_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What do we need to put in the application controller to make `set_top_3_goals` method work when the User isn't logged in or if their isn't anything in goals yet?

Because I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `goals' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `set_top_3_goals'
```

My controller code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_top_3_goals
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def set_top_3_goals
    @top_3_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.top_3
  end

  private

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a before_action with your `logged_in_user` method on your controller, before the other `before_action` call:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :set_top_3_goals
end
```

Please note that statement order matters here.